# american hospital directory - a list of all US-hospitals

Tags: data-request, usa, medical

Where can one find a list of all US hospitals with the number of licensed beds? I believe that CMS provides this data somewhere, but I cannot find it!

btw: there is a american hospital directory: Here's a list of beds per hospital 'non-federal, short-term, acute care hospitals', 
ordered by state, so in 50 clicks you'll have the data: https://www.ahd.com/state_statistics.html

I strongly suspect that this list is incomplete, and some hospitals have reported 0 beds, which seems unlikely.

Is there a dataset in a spreadsheet available somewhere?

Comment: https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Downloadable-Public-Use-Files/Cost-Reports/Hospital-2010-form.html

Answer (score 1):

One dataset you may use to check the completeness of this hospital listing would be the National Healthcare Plan and Provider Enumeration System (NPPES) dataset, collected by the Centers for Medicare and Medicaid Services, which includes participating organizations (e.g, hospitals and other facilities) and physicians.

You can get all the data in bulk from the CMS website [here](https://www.cms.gov/Regulations-and-Guidance/Administrative-Simplification/NationalProvIdentStand/DataDissemination.html).

Note it *does* not include the number of beds, but does include:

- organization address
- official contact person
- healthcare provider taxonomy (e.g. hospital unit, ambulatory health care facility, etc.)

If you want to explore the data a bit before downloading it all from CMS you can view it in Enigma Public [here](https://public.enigma.com/datasets/nppes-licensed-healthcare-providers/45b90ff7-44e5-4ff4-9042-9f51f50151f8?filter=%2B%5B%3Eentity_type_code%5B2%E2%80%A6*%5D%5D), a free platform. The link is filtered to entity type 2, organization.

I would also recommend looking at the Medicare [Hospital Compare](https://data.medicare.gov/data/hospital-compare) data, for additional hospital info from CMS, although to be clear I do not believe that it includes hospital bed count either.

(*Full disclosure: I work for Enigma, this is how I know all of this about CMS data.*)